# Window 7 Brightness slider disappeared and my display looks blotchy

Tags: windows-7, display, aero, brightness

I restarted my laptop yesterday and realised that my display looked blotchy, the aero has no smooth transitions from transparent to visible streaks , videos with rich color look blotchy and  pictures with gradient colours look blotchy.

On top of that there is absolutely no option to adjust screen brightness anywhere at all.

i'm sure it has to be a driver issue but i just cant seem to get it fixed.

I LOOK IN DRIVER MANAGER

the Monitor driver was not even there . the Generic non-PnP Monitor cant be found .

how can I get this fixed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graphics card driver is uninstalled or can't be loaded for whatever reason, and the generic driver (which doesn't support hardware-accelerated video decoding, 3D effects or brightness control) got loaded as a fallback solution.

Download and install the latest driver software for your GPU and hopefully the problem should be solved; go [here](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en) for Nvidia drivers, [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) for AMD/ATI drivers or [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx) for Intel drivers.

Comment: I had the hardest time getting it fixed . My screen went blank so I couldnt even see this answer.

I had to move my hard drive to another computer , update the driver there , take it back on my laptop and hope it works. which it did.

I had the latest NVIDIA update on my laptop but it was still running the 2009 version . so i had to update my driver to the 2013 NVIDIA vesion.